# Batch file issue: ( was unexpected at this time

Tags: batch-file

I am struggling with this and hoping someone here would be able to shed some light. This is my code:

```
:: Prerequisits
:: 1. AWS CLI
:: 2. Configure your AWS access key
::Config
set distribution=d
set devDistributionId=E2omitted
set devBucketName=dashboard.omitted.com
set prodBucketName=prod.omitted.com
set prodDistributionId=E4omitted

:: Inputs
set /P distribution=Development(d) or Production (p):
set /P sourceDir=Soruce Directory in htdocs:

:: Operations
if /I %distribution%==d (
set bucketName=%devBucketName%
set distributionId=%devDistributionId%
)

if /I %distribution%==p (
set confirmProd=n
set /P confirmProd=Copying to production. Are you sure you want to do this y/n:

echo %confirmProd%
if /I %confirmProd%==y (
set bucketName=%prodBucketName%
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%" & set "Min=%dt:~10,2%" & set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"
set "fullstamp=%YYYY%-%MM%-%DD%_%HH%-%Min%-%Sec%"
aws s3 cp s3://%bucketName% s3://%bucketName%/"%fullstamp%" --recursive
set distributionId=%prodDistributionId%
)
)

aws s3 cp C:\xampp\htdocs\%sourceDir% s3://%bucketName% --recursive
aws cloudfront create-invalidation --distribution-id %distributionId% --paths /*
```

I am suspecting that the issue is with the variable `confirmProd` and that it is not being instantiated, but I can't figure out why.

Comment: Enclose the string with double quotes and check it.

Comment: Within a block statement `(a parenthesised series of statements)`, the **entire** block is parsed and **then** executed. Any `%var%` within the block will be replaced by that variable's value **at the time the block is parsed** - before the block is executed - the same thing applies to a `FOR ... DO (block)`. Hence, setting `dt` within the block will fail as you would need `delayedexpansion` mode and `!dt! to use the value. See endless articles on SO about `delayed expansion`. Please also tell us what values you are inputting. You know - we can only assume.

Comment: Please read this help article: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: This error can also be caused by a variable not being initialized. So when you use an IF statement to compare strings, one side of the compare could be completely empty.  The best practice for comparing strings is to surround each side of the comparison in quotes. `IF "var1"=="var2" (`

Comment: Thanks for the comments I will try to do that tomorrow and let you know if it works.
What I am inputting when the job runs is:
- distribution: p
- sourceDir: production
- confirmProd: y

Comment: @Magoo I have tried using delayed expansion but that didn't quite do the trick. Check update code.

Comment: Check very carefully the variablenames you are using. `confirmProd` and `_confirmProd` are not the same animal.

Comment: @Magoo oh you're right, I followed this: http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html and thought that the underscore was part of the syntax.

I have tried that solution again after fixing it and it worked and that way is much more readable than what I suggested below, please post your answer so I can mark it as the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within a block statement (a parenthesised series of statements), the entire block is parsed and then executed. Any %var% within the block will be replaced by that variable's value at the time the block is parsed - before the block is executed - the same thing applies to a FOR ... DO (block). Hence, setting dt within the block will fail as you would need delayedexpansion mode and !dt! to use the value. See endless articles on SO about delayed expansion`.

Comment: @Naguib I rejected your edit because references outside of the Stack Exchange site-network is outside of SE control and may become unusable dead links.

Comment: Ok, no worries. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually what worked was breaking up the "sets" from the "gets" in the if conditions as per Mangoo's comment:

> Within a block statement (a parenthesised series of statements), the
>   entire block is parsed and then executed.

Here's the code that works:

```
:: Prerequisits
:: 1. AWS CLI
:: 2. Configure your AWS access key
::Config
set distribution=d
set devDistributionId=E2omitted
set devBucketName=dashboard.omitted.com
set prodBucketName=dashboard.omitted.com
set prodDistributionId=E4omitted

:: Inputs
set /P distribution=Development(d) or Production (p):
set /P sourceDir=Soruce Directory in htdocs:
if /I %distribution%==p (
set confirmProd=n
set /P confirmProd=Copying to production. Are you sure you want to do this y/n:
)

:: Operations
if /I %distribution%==d (
set bucketName=%devBucketName%
set distributionId=%devDistributionId%
)

if /I %confirmProd%==y (
set bucketName=%prodBucketName%
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%" & set "Min=%dt:~10,2%" & set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"
)
if /I %confirmProd%==y (
set "fullstamp=%YYYY%-%MM%-%DD%_%HH%-%Min%-%Sec%"
)
if /I %confirmProd%==y (
aws s3 cp s3://%bucketName% s3://%bucketName%/"%fullstamp%" --recursive
set distributionId=%prodDistributionId%
)


aws s3 cp C:\xampp\htdocs\%sourceDir% s3://%bucketName% --recursive
aws cloudfront create-invalidation --distribution-id %distributionId% --paths /*
```